# Cannot create property 'onload' on string

Tags: javascript, canvas, onload

i want to wright code that fills a canvis with a bunch of randomly selected images.

First i wrote it without randomness

`enter code here`

```
        load(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var images = [
            "https://i.imgur.com/zyXQMZ8.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/330px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bb/Png-logo.png",
            "https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png",
            "https://i.imgur.com/zyXQMZ8.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/330px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bb/Png-logo.png",
            "https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"
        ].map(function(i){
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = i;
            return img;
        });

        Promise.all(images.map(function(image) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                image.onload = resolve;
            });
        }))
        .then(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var img = images[i];
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,i*100,100,100);
        }
        });
    }
```

This worked.
now with random:

```
enter code here

load2(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var randomImageArray = [];
        for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
            for(var j=0; j<10; j++){
                randomImageArray.push(this.imageArray[this.rng(5)]);
            }
        }

        randomImageArray.map(function(i){
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = i;
                return img;
        });

        Promise.all(randomImageArray.map(function(image) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                image.onload = resolve;
            });
        }))
        .then(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var img = randomImageArray[i];
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,i*100,100,100);
        }
        });
    },
```

---

```
enter code here

data() {
    return{
        array: [],
        canvis: "",
        checked: false,
        number1: "",
        number2: "",
        numImgs: "",
        imageArray: [
            "https://i.imgur.com/zyXQMZ8.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/330px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bb/Png-logo.png",
            "https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png"
            ],
    }
},
```

---

```
enter code here

rng(reach){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * reach);
    },
```

now i always get the message: Cannot create property 'onload' on string

How do i fix that? I don't get it. ty
(this is my first post pls be nice)

Comment: `randomImageArray.map(function(i){` - you're ignoring the return value from `.map()`, so `randomImageArray` is still the URL strings, not the `<img>` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this because array.map is not changes original array but it returns changed version of original array,

so you should set the original array to new one

```js
load2(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var randomImageArray = [];
        for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
            for(var j=0; j<10; j++){
                randomImageArray.push(this.imageArray[this.rng(5)]);
            }
        }

        randomImageArray = /*<---- here*/randomImageArray.map(function(i){
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = i;
                return img;
        });

        Promise.all(randomImageArray.map(function(image) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                image.onload = resolve;
            });
        }))
        .then(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var img = randomImageArray[i];
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,i*100,100,100);
        }
        });
    },
```